# Date record from MYSQL to display in a html table based from the dates Month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql with 4 columns. 2 VARCHAR fields and 1 date field with NULL field to "Yes" and the default field "NULL" in phpmyadmin. I want to be able to display on a html table that has 12 columns one for each month (eg Jan,feb etc) that date Month in the MYSQL table to the correct month column. For example if my date field has 12/8/2019 i want that to be displayed on the August Column.

I have tried using a date field for every month and the use a form with 12 date pickers but i found that i could not have any empty date fields.

I do not know what code to use to display the date month in a month column but this is the html

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm small">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
      <th>Owner</th>
      <th>Jan</th>
      <th>Feb</th>
      <th>Mar</th>
      <th>T1 Break</th>
      <th>Apr</th>
      <th>May</th>
      <th>Jun</th>
      <th>T2 Break</th>
      <th>Jul</th>
      <th>Aug</th>
      <th>Sep</th>
      <th>T3 Break</th>
      <th>Oct</th>
      <th>Nov</th>
      <th>Dec</th>
      <th>T4 Break</th>
  </thead>
  </tr>
</Table>

For example if my date field has 12/8/2019 i want that to be displayed on the August Column.

<?php
require 'db.php';
$sqlview="SELECT * FROM booking";
$myData = mysqli_query($con, $sqlview);
while($viewrecord = mysqli_fetch_array($myData))
  {
echo "<form action=overseebooking.php method=POST>";
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_owner'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_jan'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_feb'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_march'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_t1hols'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_april'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_may'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_june'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_t2hols'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_july'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_august'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_september'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_t3hols'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_oct'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_nov'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_dec'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . $viewrecord['booking_t4hols'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit class=form-control name=update value=update" . " </td>";
echo "</form>";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: This is an SQL issue , I suggest adding `sql` tag and include your select statement that you tried.

Comment: Can you show your PHP code?

Comment: @MosesSchwartz i have added it to the original posy

Comment: @Accountant I don't think so

Comment: @MosesSchwartz OK, sorry  I misunderstood your question , I thought you were struggling with writing the SQL query to select the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how you are getting the data back but here is some idea:

Loop thru all results, get the number of the month number if this date, for each result add a `tr` in each tr add 12 `td`'s for each month column, when `$i` in the loop is `===` to your month number, add it to `$html`

See code example:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm small">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
      <th>Jan</th>
      <th>Feb</th>
      <th>Mar</th>
      <th>Apr</th>
      <th>May</th>
      <th>Jun</th>
      <th>Jul</th>
      <th>Aug</th>
      <th>Sep</th>
      <th>Oct</th>
      <th>Nov</th>
      <th>Dec</th>
  </thead>
  </tr>
<?php 
$html = "";
require 'db.php';
$sqlview="SELECT * FROM booking";
$myData = mysqli_query($con, $sqlview);
//loop thru the dates (in your case the SQL results)
while($viewrecord = mysqli_fetch_array($myData)){
    //get the month number (Jan = 1, Feb = 2 etc.)
    $monthNumber = date_parse_from_format("y-m-d", $viewrecord['date'])['month'];
    //return A tr for each result
    $html .= '<tr>';
    //a td for each month
    for($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++){
        $html .= '<td>';
        //if column is current month, display date
        $html .= ($monthNumber === ($i+1)) ? $viewrecord['date'] : "";
        $html .= '</td>';
    }
    $html .= '<tr>';
}
echo $html;
?>
<table>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198271/discussion-on-answer-by-moses-schwartz-date-record-from-mysql-to-display-in-a-ht).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using PDO to query your data and you already selected all records,
all you need to do is to process the main query result with PHP normally like any array like below:

1- Your query:

```
$data = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE")->fetchAll();
```

2- Creating month array (Put all the months you want):

```
$myMonth = array('January' => 'Jan','February' => 'Feb','March' => 'Mar');
```

3- Create arrays for each month based on $data

```
$January = array_filter($data ,function($val){
    if (in_array($val["Jan"], $myMonth)) {
        return $val;
    }
});
```

I didn't actually test the code above but the important thing is that I hope you got the idea.

After repeating that for each month, you will end up with 12 separate arrays includes all records you need for each one of them, then you can loop through them in your table into each month.

Comment: wow like i said before i am a beginner and learning fast. This is a little over my head now. :-( but i will try

Comment: That's great, the main thing you need to always remember as a beginner is to think about the type of object you are dealing with, Once you define the object type you can start searching for all available methods to deal with it then find your solution. Good luck Icelander